# Phone iOS replay media?

Tags: ios, cordova, media

I've been developing a phonegap App for both Android and iPhone.
My app display a page with image and audio in the background, and when you click a button it changes the image and play a different audio.
doing something like this

```
function playMedia(src)
{
    myMedia = new Media(src, onSuccess);
    myMedia.play();
}
```

And the next audio function looks like that:

```
function nextAudio()
{
    myMedia.stop();
    myMedia.release();
    playMedia(src);
}
```

On android this code works perfectly fine.
On iOS it works for the first time, but when I change the audio src, it would only work if  the app lose focus and then regain it. 
for example, minimizing the app, or open the notifications menu.

How can I solve this issue?